# set position para un RecyclerView con gridLayout Manager en Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` con `gridlayout manager` con las letras del abecedario quiero hacer algo similar al `SmoothScroller` para el `LinearLayout manager`

```
smoothScroller = new
                LinearSmoothScroller(activity) {
                    @Override
                    protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                        return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                    }
                };
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(0);
        getManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

esto porque necesito que se llame un evento `onScrollStateChanged` que tengo en el `OnScrollListener` de mi `RecyclerView` con un `SnapHelper` adjunto quiero que cuando inicie la aplicacion salga seleccionada la letra a y su metodo creado para esta cada que se obtiene la snapposition.

gracias.

Comment: Te da algún error? Que has intentado?

Comment: no me da ningun error simplemente no hace nada intente con agregando el metodo @Override getHorizontalSnapPreference()  tambien pero no hace nada,  el codigo sirve perfecto con un LinearLayout manager pero con el gridLayout no.